# Is it possible to buy SSL cert ONLY for one subdomain?

Tags: ssl, domain, deployment, ssl-certificate

I want to deploy my application with following domains:

domain.com, www.domain.com - no ssl required, static pages only

sub.domain.com - ssl required

Can I buy SSL cert only for sub.domain.com or do I need to buy wildcard cert for my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: Yes you can.
The item you need to look for is Subject Alternative Names (SANs) you can purchase one of these from VeriSign, from 1-3years.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 4):

You can buy a cert just for sub.domain.com